# Why is the map $G \to \text{T}G, x \to d(L_x)_e(X)$ smooth for lie group $G$?

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

Let $G$ be a Lie group and $L_a$ be the left multiplication map $x\mapsto ax$. Let $X\in \text{T}_e(G)$ be a fixed tangent vector, I wonder why the map

$$G \to \text{T}G, x \to d(L_x)_e(X)$$

is smooth.

I know I need to use the fact that the multiplication map is smooth somewhere. I have trouble in making use of the smooth structure of $\text{T}G$.

Comment: See that $d(L_x)_e(X)= X_x$

Comment: @GuyFsone  what do you mean by $X_x$?

Answer (score 0):

I´m gonna change your notation a little bit because is not very suggestive. Let´s represent the map as
*Vg := (dLg)(e)(X)*
where *X* is the vector at the tangent space to the identity, then:
*Vg := (dLg)(e)(X) = (dLg)(e)(r´(0)) = d(Lg∘r)(0) = d(μ(g;r(t)))(0)*
where *r* is a curve going trough the identity whose differential at the *0* is *X* and *μ* is the product map in the Lie group.
So we know that the product map is smooth, so is particularly smooth in *g*, so also is it´s differential.